# TDBGrid(s) Compare Values and Paint

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

On this form, there are (3) TDBGrids. OnCalcCellColors  or OnDrawDataCell, need to compare a value in grid1 with a corresponding value in grid3. The row color for all (3) grids will be determined by the comparison. >= Red, < Green etc...

The coloring is easy. However without ARow & ACol cell references, not sure how to index the grid values. Works great on a single grid.
Doing the comparison in this manner with negate the need to  Enumerate the data set.

Comment: Are the datasets for all three grids the same or different?

Comment: Not enough information. What is the relation (linkage) between the three grids? When one is scrolled, what makes the others scroll?

Comment: unclear what you are asking. Does a certain row in grid1 needs to compare with the value of a certain row in another grid ? Which row ? a certain row ? all Rows ? Please describe your problem if you want an answer

Comment: Since you are using data aware controls... you should be doing the comparison in your datasets, not with the usual control centered logic. Add some calculated field to the dataset. Use the dataset's OnCalcField event to compare the values. Use the fields value to decide the cell's color.